# Is it possible to force update a project without running a default lifecycle phase?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have yet to find documentation on what exactly triggers the force update and I've seen that it behaves differently depending on which lifecycle phase is run. This has led me to the conclusion though that maven certainly cares which phase you are running if you try to force update (with a -U) and ignores the force update if it doesn't need to.

I'd like to force an update even when I am not running a default lifecycle phase directly. My use case is in releasing my app with timestamped snapshot versions with the command:

```
mvn clean release:perform release:prepare -U
```

I'm seeing that even though the snapshots are versioned, internally it is getting the latest SNAPSHOT version in its local repo. If I run `mvn compile -U` first, then my snapshots are updated, and the release happens as expected.

I am curious as to why the timestamp version isn't used to pull the new artifact from nexus, but I figure it has something to do with the more narrow-minded release plugin rather than with maven itself.

Since I'm accepting defeat with the release-plugin, is there a way to force the update without running a separate (and unnecessary) lifecycle phase. Or a way to pass in the -U to be run by the maven release plugin when building my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are mixing different concepts. You are calling:

```
mvn release:prepare...
```

which does not start a [life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in contradictions it runs the release plugin with it's particular goal [`prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) and of course `.. release:perform` runs the goal [`perform`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html).

Furthermore the release plugin starts a sub process (starting maven in subfolder target/checkout) with the created release (tagged state) which usually does **not** transfer the -U option to this sub process. This can be accomplished by using `mvn -Darguments="..."'.

But if you like to force an update of snapshot's during your build you can simply using `mvn -U...` like:

```
mvn -U clean package
```

This means simple let maven checks in Nexus are there newer SNAPSHOT's if yes download them to local repository instead of waiting till time out for updating of SNAPSHOT's has come (see [updatePolicy](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)).

If you like to change your versions in your build without the maven-release-plugin you can take a look at the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) but in this case you need to do your tagging etc. yourself.

Comment: But why doesn't the release plugin pull down the timestamp version (as though it were a release version)? Instead I need to update all my snapshots locally for the process to use the correct timestamp version.

Comment: bah, I couldn't edit my comment above. This really must be a maven issue, since in the release plugin I'm sure would use maven internals to resolve the dependencies. And it looks like the -U option works great passed in through the arguments (-Darguments="-U"). I had thought I tried that, but apparently I missed that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't let `release` candidate ever dependent on `SNAPSHOTS`, if you still want to do it then

```
mvn dependency:resolve -U
```

Comment: This may be what we go forward with as the output of resolved dependencies may be useful, however, I'd hope there's still a way to update snapshots without making me do extra processing. Good to bring up about the snapshots and to explain our use case, we are still actively developing our app and performing these releases at the end of each 2-week iteration. We have many modular dependencies that are also under active development as part of this. Once we do our first official release we will be releasing all dependencies as well as the app itself.

Comment: [Maven Release plugins](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) takes already care of that.